# Determine if heaviest edge in minimax path is greater than threshold

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a graph G = (V,E)

I am concerned with minimizing the heaviest edge in the path from s to t

The only edge that I actually care about is the heaviest edge and whether it is above my threshold.

Is there a way to determine, given the source and destination, whether the heaviest edge is above a threshold?

I know that you can calculate the MST and get the path directly, but I am mainly interested in whether there is a linear time algorithm to find the heaviest edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to determine, given the source and destination, whether the heaviest edge is above a threshold?

Yes: start at the source and perform breadth-first search or depth-first search, while ignoring any edges over the threshold. If the search reaches the destination, then the answer is "no"; otherwise it is "yes".

Comment: Thanks :) so simple, I knew it had to do with BFS just couldn't come up with that detail